# Merge multiple files at the differences

Tags: text-processing, merge

I'm running a scripts on a text file, and I want to merge its contents. Let's say that the file is called "file1".

file1:

> This is some text, wow!

Now I have few versions after running scripts.

file2:

> My<> is some text, wow!

file3:

> Yours<> is some text, wow!

file4:

> This is some txt<>, wow!

As you can see, some words are changed to another, and have <> added. Now I want to merge these files, so that the words are merged if they got changed:

Output:

> My<>Yours<> is some txt<>, wow!

The order doesn't really matter; they just have to be merged. Is there tool that could make this easy?

Comment: contents should be merged from `file1..4` ? and how you are deciding that which word will remain in final output file ?

Comment: @Rahul, from what I understand, all changes are in final output and that the order doesn't matter.. for ex: `My<>Yours<>` could be `Yours<>My<>` instead

Comment: @Rahul yes, essentially files 2..4 have the same contents as file1, but some of the contents might be changed into `word<>`; we merge by the rule: if the word got changed in at least one file, merge the changed versions and replace old word with changed merged version. Thus, `text` -> `txt<>`, `This` -> `My<>Yours<>` (or, as noted, `Yours<>My<>`) and `some` -> `some`. We might merge files 1..4 or 2..4, doesn't matter; we won't need anything from file1(except for original order, if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any tools that would do that, but it's not hard to code. Here's a snippet of perl:

```
perl -E 'for $i (1..4) { open ($file,"<","file${i}"); { local $/; @{$words[$i]} = split " ",<$file>; }; close($file); }; for $i (0..scalar(@{$words[1]})-1) { $p=0; for $j (2..4) {  if ($words[1][$i] ne $words[$j][$i]) { print $words[$j][$i]; $p++ } } unless ($p) { print $words[1][$i] }; print " "; } print "\n"'
```

A lot of things could be improved, the first thing I would address if I had to use it would be the extra space at the end of the line, I would probably add the output words to an array and use the join function, but I find the task to strange to actually implement that.